# Solving dependent systems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When I'm solving a system of equations and realize that I have a dependent system, I need to express the answer in terms of y = {some value} where x is any real number, OR x = {some value} where y is any real number. How do I choose whether to

For instance, I have this problem in my homework:

```
x+4y = 5
5x + 20y = 25

x = 5-4y

5(5-4y) + 20 y = 25
25-20y+20y = 25
25 = 25 : DEPENDENT SYSTEM
```

I then solve for x using the first equation:

```
x + 4y = 5
```

And arrive at the answer of:

```
x = -4y + 5, where y is any real number
```

However, the answer in the back of the packet is:

```
y = -(x/4) + (5/4) where x is any real number
```

I see how they arrived at this, but my question is: Why did they choose to solve for y instead of solving for x? Is this choice arbitrary? Would my answer be correct as well?

Comment: Just to elaborate slightly -- as ZettaSuro says, when we interpret the result in terms of analytic geometry, it is commonplace to write the equations of lines as $ \ y = \frac{5}{4} - \frac{1}{4}x $, so many people answer that way.  But the equation of the line can also be given in "general form" as $ \ x + 4y - 5  = 0 \ $, which is also a valid expression; your answer would _also_ be correct.  In other applications, the results from a linearly dependent system often have no preference as to which variable is "independent": it is the _relation_ between the variables that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a standard mathematical convention to express a function in 2D space as $x$ being the independent variable, and $y$ being the dependent variable (dependent on $x$). Your answer is still correct, just a different way of expressing it.

This is because $x$ is usually the horizontal axis, and $y$ is usually the vertical axis, and looking at a function from left to right is easier to interpret than when looking at it from top to bottom.